# Recognizing strings with slight differences as same in R

Tags: string, r, text

Quick question: Is there a built-in R function that allows for recognition between two strings of equal length lengths but with one or two imperfect characters?

Ex:

```
>df1<-c("HELLOSTACK")

>df2<-c("HELLUSTACC")

>someBuiltInFunct(df1, df2)
>[1] TRUE
```

Or something to that effect. 
Thanks in advance! The amount of learning I have received from the knowledgable members of this forum has been invaluable!

Comment: Maybe the `stringdist` function contained in the equally named package is also helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can look at `agrep`, but would have to play with the "`max.distance`" argument:

```
> agrep(df1, df2, max = 1)
integer(0)

> agrep(df1, df2, max = 2)
[1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks Ananda! I will do some research on it.